# Communication from child view controller to container view controller

Tags: ios, uikit

I am building a view controller hierarchy.
I have a child view controller 2 levels deep from the container view controller.

This child view controller has a button to perform a certain action.

What's the best way to have this communicated to the container view controller.
I have tried sending a message using the responder chain.
Having a delegate seems super tricky given that it's 2 levels deep.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to find the contain ViewController,replace the `ContainViewController` with the Class you have

```
- (ContainViewController *)containViewController
{
    UIViewController *iter = self.parentViewController;
    while (iter) {
        if ([iter isKindOfClass:[ContainViewController class]]) {
            return (ContainViewController *)iter;
        } else if (iter.parentViewController && iter.parentViewController != iter) {
            iter = iter.parentViewController;
        } else {
            iter = nil;
        }
    }  
    return nil;
}
```